# Python and Beautifulsoup - How do I write the data to .csv with a newline

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

collectedData = []
#Open File

"""with open('scraped_urls.txt','r') as urls:
   lines = urls.read().splitlines()

urls.close()"""
#End Open File
lines = ['https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/1300614/A-A-Global-Industries-Holding-Company-Inc/13853398/A-A-Global-Industries-Holding-Company-Inc-401K-Profit-Sharing-Plan/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/718188/A-A-Maintenance-Enterprise-Inc/756688/A-A-Maintenance-Enterprise-Inc-401K-Plan-And-Trust/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/494577/A-A-Manufacturing-Company-Inc/506539/A-A-Manufacturing-Company-Inc-Retirement-Employee-Savings-Plan/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/377455/A-A-Quality-Appliance-Inc/382537/A-A-Quality-Appliance-Inc-401K-Plan/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/129644/A-A-Safety-Inc/131643/A-A-Safety-Inc-401K-Retirement-Plan/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/318493/A-B-Electric-Co-Inc/323132/A-B-Electric-Co-Profit-Sharing-Plan/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/391445/A-B-Precision-Metals-Inc/396610/A-B-Precision-Metals-Inc-401K-Plan/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/492708/A-D-Environmental-Services-Inc/504653/A-D-Environmental-Services-Inc-401K-Plan/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/222104/A-D-Management-Co-Inc/225792/A-D-Management-Co-Inc-401K-Plan/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/200362/A-E-Incorporated/203693/A-E-Incorporated-401K-Profit-Sharing-Plan-And-Trust/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/440838/A-E-Management-Inc/446748/Archways-401K-Retirement-Plan/',
'https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/45363/A-E-Stores-Inc/46054/A-E-Stores-Inc-And-Affiliated-Companies-401K-Plan/']


for xurl in lines:
    pagedata = []
  try:
    url = xurl
except:
    pass
thepage = requests.get(url)
urlsoup = BeautifulSoup(thepage.text, "html.parser")

# Company Name
try:
    companyName = urlsoup.find(class_="name").text
except:
    pass

#Rating Number
try:
    ratingNumber = urlsoup.find(class_="rating-number").text
except:
    pass

#RATINGS FOR PLAN
try:
    cost = urlsoup.find_all(class_="ratings-text")[0].text
    generosity = urlsoup.find_all(class_="ratings-text")[1].text
    par = urlsoup.find_all(class_="ratings-text")[2].text
    deferrals = urlsoup.find_all(class_="ratings-text")[3].text
    balance = urlsoup.find_all(class_="ratings-text")[4].text
    planComp = cost+", "+generosity+", "+par+", "+deferrals+", "+balance
except:
    pass

#ADDITIONAL YEARS WORKING
try:
    addedYears = urlsoup.find_all(class_="did-you-know-number")[0].text
    addedYearsText = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-small-label")[0].text
    lostSavings = urlsoup.find_all(class_="did-you-know-number")[1].text
    lostSavingsText = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-small-label")[1].text
    additionalYears = addedYears+", "+addedYearsText+", "+lostSavings+", "+lostSavingsText+", "
except:
    pass

#ADDRESS
try:
    address = urlsoup.find_all(style="display: none;")[2].text
    address = address.replace("\n", " ")
    zip = urlsoup.find_all(style="display: none;")[3].text
    location = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-main-body-text")[0].text
    location = location.replace(" ", "").replace(",", " ")
    mainBody = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-main-body-text")[0].text
    fullAddress = address+", "+location+", "+zip
    fullAddress = fullAddress.replace("\n", " ")
except:
    pass

#PLAN DATA
try:
    industry = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-main-body-text")[1].text
except:
    industry = "Nothing Here"
try:
    administrator = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-main-body-text")[2].text
except:
    administrator = "Nothing Here"
try:
    netAssets = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-main-body-text")[3].text
except:
   netAssets = "Nothing Here"
try:
    totalPar = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-main-body-text")[4].text
except:
    totalPar = "Nothing Here"
try:
    avgBal = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-main-body-text")[5].text
except:
    avgBal = "Nothing Here"
try:
    rollOver = urlsoup.find_all(class_="fp-main-body-text")[6].text
except:
    rollOver = "Nothing Here"

planData = industry+", "+administrator+", "+netAssets+", "+totalPar+", "+avgBal+", "+rollOver
planData = planData.replace("\r", "")

#Filtering data below 
addedYears = addedYears.replace("\n", " ")


#DATA ABOUT TO BE WRITTEN TO FILE
completeData = companyName, fullAddress, additionalYears, planComp, planData
print(completeData)





with open('collected_data.csv', 'a') as output:

    for i in completeData:
        output.write("{}\n".format(i))
    output.close()
```

I'm trying to save the data into a csv file but when I open it up the data is all over the place. I'm including some links here so you can see what I mean but the actual program opens a file obviously. In excel the data is like company name then the address on a new line. I want my data to be formatted like this:
column 1        column 2     column 3 etc etc etc
company name     address      etc etc etc

that write code worked when it was one line but now its crazy. Teach me master.

Comment: you are writing a value per line, if it is a `csv` file I would think you want to print them separated by a comma, in a line? Also first try calling `.strip()` to every value before assigning it to `completeData`

Comment: Use the `csv` module which handles the comma delimiters and line breaks. SO has thousands of python questions of writing to csvs.